# Why std::next stuck when feed with begin of a empty map

Tags: c++, stl, iterator, std

This piece of code stuck. Can someone give a clue?

```
map<int,char> m;
auto begin=m.begin() // {first=0, second=0, '\000'}
auto end=m.end() // {first=0, second=0, '\000'}
auto it=std::next(m.begin(),1); // it stucked
```

Comment: What do you mean by "stuck"? I any case, I don't think you're allowed to increment an `.end()` iterator (it causes UB).

Comment: What do you expect it to do?

Answer (score 3):

You mustn’t call `std::next` on an invalid iterator, or an iterator that points to `end()`. This is undefined behaviour.

Comment: Hmm. It sounds a little weird. Can not `stl` do something for an end `iterator` for `std::next`?

Comment: Sure, it can do something. It's undefined behavior. It can 'stuck', it can crash your program, it can reformat your hard disk, .....